# Is there a way to iterate through an array and update it in-place using iter()?

Tags: python, iterator, in-place

I have an array that I want to update the next row every time a function is called. Here is a toy example of the functionality I'm looking for:

```
import numpy as np


x = np.zeros((10, 3))
new_data = np.ones((1, 3))

y = iter(x)
for i in range(5):
    z = next(y)
    z = new_data

print(x)
```

In the above example, I was hoping to start with x as an array of all zeros, and end up with x as an array with all ones in the first five rows, and all zeros in the last five rows.

Is there any way to iterate through the array x, and update it "in-place".

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I have some data that can get updated by multiple functions and I don't want to have to keep a global counter of the current row that needs to be updated. I'd rather just call something like next(array_iterator) to always get the next row.

Comment: That example does not update `x` after it is created

Comment: I understand, when I originally tried it, I was expecting / hoping that y would just be pointing to the next row in x, so any change to y would change that row in x. I'm looking for a way to do something along those lines.